# MongoDB aggregate reduce mergeObjects field name from value

Tags: mongodb

I have an array in a Mongo document that has a number of properties.  I want to produce a document that has a single object that represents the array.

```
{
  scores_array: [
    { name: "One", score: 40, key: "abc" },
    { name: "Two", score: 50, key: "def" },
    { name: "Three", score: 40, key: "abc" },
    { name: "Four", score: 40, key: "ghi" },
  }
}
```

What I want is to be able to query for documents that have a particular value for two of the properties in the array, for example, `{ name: "One", score: 40 }`.

I can use `$in` to find documents that have the matching key or value, and I could redact them to filter them out but I need to reference them again later in the same pipeline, so I'm trying to find a way to filter without removing anything from the documents.

My plan is to use `$reduce` to produce a new property that looks like this:

```
scores_summary: {
  One: 40,
  Two: 50,
  Three: 40,
  Four: 40,
}
```

I'm having trouble getting the `$reduce` syntax right.  Here's what I've got:

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
     $match: {
       scores_array: {$exists: true}
     }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      scores_summary: { 
        $reduce: {
          input: "$scores_array", 
          initialValue: {}, 
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$value", 
              {
                "$$this.name":"$$this.score"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
]);
```

This gives me "Unrecognized expression $$this.name".  If I replace that with a constant, I get an output that looks right, except for that property.

Is there a reason I can't use `$$this.name` as the property name in the `mergeObjects` in a reduce?  Hoping I'm just missing something.

(I'm using Mongo 3.4 currently which means I can't just fall back to `$expr`).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$map` and `$arrayToObject`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      scores_array: {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      scores_summary: {
        "$arrayToObject": {
          $map: {
            input: "$scores_array",
            "in": {
              k: "$$this.name",
              v: "$$this.score"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eUpb-NkJfQp)**